# Golang GUI - how to solve error "undefined: gtk.Init..." with gotk3 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, go, gtk3

I try to build GTK3 Golang applications on Windows 10 (x64) by this Wiki:

[Installing-on-Windows](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/wiki/Installing-on-Windows)

But get this errors:

```
go build example.go

\#command-line-arguments 

.\\example.go:10:9: undefined: gtk.Init 

.\\example.go:14:21: undefined: gtk.WindowNew 

.\\example.go:14:35: undefined: gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL 

.\\example.go:20:13: undefined: gtk.MainQuit 

.\\example.go:24:19: undefined: gtk.LabelNew 

.\\example.go:40:9: undefined: gtk.Main
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried enabling CGO_FLAGS and CGO_LD_FLAGS as https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/issues/373#issuecomment-413767129 ?

Comment: I deleted everything and followed the instructions from Wiki again. 

Because the command of Chocolatey: 

`choco install golang`

installs Go to the folder "c:\Program Files\Go\" I replace command from Wiki 
`echo 'export PATH=/c/Go/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`
to 
`echo 'export PATH=/c/Program\ Files/Go/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: After restart mingw64 I create c:\tools\msys64\home\admin\example.go described at github.com/gotk3/gotk3 
Next in mingw64 terminal run: 

`go mod init gogtk`
`go mod tidy`
`go build example.go`

Over time I get example.exe But it works only in mingw64 terminal (# ./example.exe)

When I try to lunch example.exe from Windows Explorer I get many errors that many libraries was not found.
Next I add to Windows `PATH` c:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin\ and can run example.exe in Windows Explorer.